# How to take the sum of a float list?

Tags: python

My code

```
final = replace.split()
for word in final:
    if word >= "0":
        if word <= "9":
            add = (word.split())
            floats = [float(x) for x in add]
            print(floats)
```

It gives me

```
[3236.789]
[4.3]
[6.7]
[5.2]
```

when I use `print(sum(floats))` it gives me the same thing without brackets.

```
3236.789
4.3
6.7
5.2
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the total of these numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of those is a single value in a list. It probably makes more sense to create an empty list outside of the loop and append to it. Judging from your output, I think your list comprehension is unnecessary. Try something like this:

```
nums = []
for word in replace.split():
    # Do the checks if you must
    nums.extend(float(word))

print(sum(nums))
```

---

It may be really simple, but it might help to add a few print statements throughout the logic of your code. Try `print(word)` after the `for` loop to see if your data in the state you expect. I say this because judging from your code and output there appear to be several unnecessary operations taking place.

Also, `floats` is a bad name for a variable; it's too similar to the builtin `float` which you also make use of. Same goes for `replace` as it is a string method.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but is `from math import *` required to do sum() or no?

Comment: Nope. `sum` is a python built-in. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html